# How to find the max xpath value in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm working on scraping data in Selenium using xpaths. I want to iterate across xpaths with differing numeric values. For example, I want to iterate across the following xpath: `"//*[@id="content-core"]/div/p[i]"` with `i` being the values `1` to `n`.

Is there a function or code to find `n`, the maximum number in a given Xpath equation, so I know when to stop the loop?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It totally depends on the website. Use `beautifulsoup` to parse the HTML and figure out how many `<p>`s are in that particular `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try-except` block, like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

i = 1

while True:
    try:
        xpath = f"//*[@id="content-core"]/div/p[{i}]"
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        i += 1

    except NoSuchElementException: 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` to solve it. For example, assume if you have extract an `html` of an `url`, as follows:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
html = etree.HTML(data)
```

Then, you can get the length of the label `p`.

```
len = int(html.xpath('count(//*[@id="content-core"]/div//p)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the elements len and then loop through them.

```
n=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-core']/div/p"))
for i in range(n):
  try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-core']/div/p["+i+"]")
  except:
    break
```